# Open image from PictureBox in windows photo viewer using ImageLocation

Tags: c#, .net, picturebox

I am trying to open an image from the PictureBox using ImageLocaton Property, because I want in the future to store the images on an online Database.

I've tried this code but says that `pictureBox1.ImageLocation.ToString()` is null:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(pictureBox1.ImageLocation.ToString());
}
```

I also have seen it in the properties tab, but why?

[image: I also have seen it in the properties tab, but why?]

Comment: How do you load images into that picture box?

Comment: Not from a file location.  You'd have to save it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the ImageLocation of the pictureBox to set its Image (not get it that is obviously null if not set):

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = someurl;
```

Comment: But if I added a image in the Properties Window , shouldn't also save the Image Location?

Comment: @MihaiDorinIliescu Nope, Image property is typeof Image while ImageLocation is typeof string, they are not related.